# Create java stream with supplier lazyly

Tags: java, java-stream, lazy-sequences

it is possible, with Java 8 stream API, to create Stream that is not evaluated until is necessary?

I mean.

I have a stream that processes a list of elements, in one of the middle operations (map) I have to read go through another stream and I want to have that Stream in another variable to be used through all other first stream objects, but if there Are no objects to process I would like to avoid process second stream.

I think it's easier to check with code:

```
Message[] process(@Nullable Message[] messages) {
    Stream<Function> transformationsToApply =
            transformations
                    .stream()
                    .filter(transformation -> transformationIsEnabled(transformation.getLeft()))
                    .map(Pair::getRight);

    return Arrays.stream(messages != null ? messages : new Message[0])
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(agentMessage -> {
                transformationsToApply.forEach(transformation -> processMessage(transformation, agentMessage));
                return agentMessage;
            })
            .toArray(Message[]::new);
}
```

My doubt is about first one stream generation, I would like to return stream based on the list that I processed, but I only to want to do if it is gonna be used (And use same for all message elemets).

Any idea..?

Comment: The operation in the second stream's `.map` will cause an exception. The stream's `forEach` terminal operation would be called multiple times, which is not allowed. Why not return a stream and let the caller run `.toArray` only when necessary?

Comment: You should specify the type parameters of `Function`, using raw types will disable some compile-time type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams are not stateful, so there's no easy way to have it do something only when the first element is processed. In this case, you could just check the `messages` parameter and return early if there's nothing to do:

```
Message[] process(@Nullable Message[] messages) {
    if (messages == null || messages.length == 0) return new Message[0];

    List<Function> transformationsToApply = transformations.stream()
            .filter(transformation -> transformationIsEnabled(transformation.getLeft()))
            .map(Pair::getRight)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return Arrays.stream(messages)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(agentMessage -> {
                transformationsToApply.forEach(transformation -> processMessage(transformation, agentMessage));
                return agentMessage;
            })
            .toArray(Message[]::new);
}
```

I also fixed the issue with reusing the `transformationsToApply` stream, you need to make it a collection before you can iterate over it multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, your `transformationsToApply` is not evaluated until you attach a [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy;
>   executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually
>   perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when
>   traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the
>   given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until
>   the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

Comment: And the value of the processed stream will be used for all iterations? Or it will be calculated each time? That's my doubt and that's why I'm saving it in a variable.

Comment: Your expression inside `.map` will cause exception will cause exception since the stream can be consumed only once. I suggest you to store result of `transformationsToApply.toList` to a local variable and reuse it in your `.map` method